# get all values from array of objects in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Assuming, I have data like below

```
const data = [{"No":100,"Name":"john","assigned":"James","status":"available"},{"No":200,"Name":"Abhi","assigned":"James","status":"blocked"}]
```

what is the best way to get as below output ?

```
const data = [["100", "john", "James", "available"],["200", "Abhi", "James", "blocked"]];
```

I tried using lodash.

```
_.values(data)
```

But i got output as

```
[object Object],[object Object].
```

Comment: use `array.map()` or  `_.map()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **pure js**:

```js
const data = [{"No":100,"Name":"john","assigned":"James","status":"available"},{"No":200,"Name":"Abhi","assigned":"James","status":"blocked"}];

data1 = data.map( function(v) {
   return Object.values( v );
});

console.log(data1);
```

**Using lodash:**

```js
const data = [{"No":100,"Name":"john","assigned":"James","status":"available"},{"No":200,"Name":"Abhi","assigned":"James","status":"blocked"}];

data1 = _.map( data, function(v) {
   return _.values( v );
});

console.log(data1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data
  .map(element => Object.values(element));
```